# How to convert VisualStudio project to Eclipse CDT

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse, project, migrate

The question is already in the title. I have a Visual Studio project which builds a .dll. Now I need the same library for MacOS X and linux, so I would like to convert the VS project to Eclipse and compile it for both platforms. 
I will be very thankful for any tips, hints or guidance!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to know which compiler you have to use, then 
 1. you can convert the project in a MakeFile and create a Makefile project in Eclipse
 2. or you can try to convert the project in a compiler-specific project.